# How do I create a regex in Emacs for exactly 3 digits?

Tags: regex, emacs

I want to create a regexp in Emacs that matches exactly 3 digits.   For example, I want to match the following:

```
123
345
789
```

But not

```
1234
12
12 23
```

If I use `[0-9]+` I match any single string of digits.   I thought `[0-9]{3}` would work, but when tested in re-builder it doesn't match anything.

Comment: When testing the answers below try M-x regexp-builder; it's very very helpful.

Comment: If you use regexp-builder, keep in mind that you need to use one more backslash for each escape, since it is building an expression that you could embed in code, not one you would use at the (query-)replace-regexp prompt.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you're entering the regex interactively, and want to use `{3}`, you need to use backslashes to escape the curly braces.  If you don't want to match any part of the longer strings of numbers, use `\b` to match word boundaries around the numbers.  This leaves:

```
\b[0-9]\{3\}\b
```

For those wanting more information about `\b`, see [the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash):

> matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. Thus, `\bfoo\b`
>   matches any occurrence of `foo` as a separate word. 
>   `\bballs?\b` matches `ball` or `balls` as a separate word.
>   `\b` matches at the beginning or end of the buffer regardless of what text appears next to it.

If you do want to use this regex from elisp code, as always, you must escape the backslashes one more time.  For example:

```
(highlight-regexp "\\b[0-9]\\{3\\}\\b")
```

Answer (score 11):

`[0-9][0-9][0-9]`, `[0-9]{3}` or `\d{3}` don't work because they also match "1234".

So it depends on what the delimiter is.

If it's in a variable, then you can do `^/[0-9]{3}/$`. If it's delimited by whitespace you could do `\w+[0-9]{3}\w+`

Answer (score 5):

You should use this:

```
"^\d{3}$"
```

Comment: Emacs regexps don't support \d.

Comment: ech, then what should be used in this case?

Comment: Avoid \d if critical to match 0-9 ONLY! See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex

Answer (score 3):

As others point out, you need to match more than just the three digits. Before the digits you have to have either a line-start or something that is not a digit. If emacs supports \D, use it. Otherwise use the set [^0-9].

In a nutshell:

```
(^|\D)\d{3}(\D|$)
```

Comment: \b catches the (^|\D) and (\D|$) a lot more easily.  It won't work when the thing you're matching on is not a word character, but \B often works in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

When experimenting with regular expressions in Emacs, I find **regex-tool** quite useful:

ftp://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/emacs/regex-tool.el

Not an answer (the question is answered already), just a general tip.

Answer (score 0):

[0-9][0-9][0-9] will match a *minimum* of 3 numbers, so as Joe mentioned, you have to (at a minimum) include \b or anything else that will delimit the numbers. Probably the most sure-fire method is:

[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]

Comment: As Antti implied, this approach suffers from not matching at the beginning or end of the file/line (depending on options).  \b catches those.

Answer (score -3):

It's pretty simple:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: Answer is obviously wrong. I wonder why it got +votes at all.