# Regex Optional Groups?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I seem to have confused myself with a preg_match regex I'm doing, so fresh eyes and help would be appreciated.

My current regex is as follows:

```
/<!--menu:start:\(([0-9])\,([0-9])\)-->(.*?)<!--menu:end-->/se
```

I am looking to make the number input and colon e.g. :(1,4) optional, so it would match:

```
<!--menu:start--><!--menu:end-->
```

or

```
<!--menu:start:(0,3)--><!--menu:end-->
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Enclose with a non matching group and set it to optional : `(?:...)?`

```
/<!--menu:start(?::\(([0-9])\,([0-9])\))?-->(.*?)<!--menu:end-->/se
```

Answer (score 29):

Like this:

```
/<!--menu:start(?::\((\d),(\d)\))?-->(.*?)<!--menu:end-->/se
```

I've added a non-capturing group, `(?: )`, around the part you want to be optional, and then suffixed it with a question mark: `(?:<optional content>)?`

Comment: Haha, that's a close tie... :)

Comment: Thanks guys :) Had to choose one!

Comment: +1 to Blixt for a clearer explanation; the `(?...)?` is a tad confusing.

Comment: +1 for using `\d` instead of `0-9`. Future proofs the query, for when society adds new digits, like eleventy.

Answer (score 5):

This uses an optional non-capturing group -- `(?: )?` -- to match your optional part, and also `\d` instead of `[0-9]` to match digits:

```
/<!--menu:start(?::\((\d),(\d)\))?-->(.*?)<!--menu:end-->/se
```

If numbers in parentheses can consist of more than one digit, use this one instead:

```
/<!--menu:start(?::\((\d+),(\d+)\))?-->(.*?)<!--menu:end-->/se
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using \d instead of [0-9]?

Comment: None actually, except that \d is shorter. :-)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex for differences of \d and [0-9]