# Regular Expression doesn't count characters that are part of * quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

the regular expression: `/([a-z][0-9]*){6,12}/i`

so i am expecting this to return true if a string contains more than 6 and less than 12 characters even if there aren't 6 alphabetical characters, but it doesn't, i want "123456789a" to return true and "abcdefghi1", but the first one doesn't.

```
var myRegEx = /([a-z][0-9]*){6,12}/i;


function checkIt() {
var myString = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

if(myRegEx.test(myString) == true) {
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].className = "trueOrFalse true";
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "True";
}
else {
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].className = "trueOrFalse false";
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "False";
}

}
```

Comment: How is `"123456789a"` supposed to match `/([a-z][0-9]*){6,12}/i` ? It doesn't start with a character in `[a-z]`.

Comment: try regex101.com first

Comment: Please take the time to eliminate irrelevant code from your example. The vast majority of that example has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/y71mudms/2/

the correct regex is

```
var myRegEx = /^[0-9]{6,11}[a-z]{1}$/i;
```

we search exact match of digits + 1 char from 6 to 12

```
/^[0-9]{6,11}[a-z]{1}$/i;
 ^  ^    ^           ^
 |  |    |           |_ end of string
 |  |    |
 |  |    |_ from 6 min to 11 max repetitions
 |  |
 |  |_ digit 0-9 include all digits 
 |
 |_ begin of string
```

ref. [6 digits regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758414/6-digits-regular-expression)

Comment: here let me explain: i want the regex to return true if there are more than 6 and less than 12 alphabetic characters or a mix of alphabetic and numeric characters, but not numeric characters alone.

Comment: i can acheve this with " /([a-z][0-9]*){6,12}/i" but the problem is, the numbers don't count, so it doesn't return true until there are at least 6 a-z characters, i want it to return true even if there's one a-z character and the rest are numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap a check for the string-length around your regex-conditions:

```
if string.length > 6 && string.length < 12) {
  // if regex...
}
```