# Make sure username is not a phone number

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a mobile website and I would like the user to be able to login via username or phone number. I think the easist way to validate their response it to not allow them to signup using a phone number as their user name.

The problem is that I'll need to check if the input of the username field is JUST a 10 or 11 digit number. This is where my inexperance in regex comes to my disadvantage. I'm hoping to try something like

```
    function do_reg($text, $regex)
{
    if (preg_match($regex, $text)) {
        return TRUE;
    } 
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

     $username = $_POST['username'];
     if(do_reg($username, '[0-9]{10,11}')){
            die('cannot use a 10 or 11 digit number as a username');
     }
```

The above regex is matching all numbers that are 10-11 digits long. I think maybe I need a way to say if the ONLY thing in the user input field is a 10-11 digit number get mad otherwise release the butterflies and rainbows.

**EDIT:** For the record I decided to make sure the username wasn't JUST a number. Thought this would be simpler and I didn't like the idea of having people use numbers as logins.

So I ended up with

```
if (!empty($username) && preg_match('/^\d+$/', $username )) {
              die('username cannot be a number');
}
```

Thanks for the help all.

Comment: Your `do_reg` function has no reason to exist. It's useless - use `preg_match` instad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost correct, except PCRE in PHP requires delimiters, and probably some anchors to make sure the field consists only of numbers.

```
 if(do_reg($username, '/^\d{10,11}$/')){
//                     ^^         ^^
```

And probably use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

(BTW, you should just call `preg_match` directly:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\d{10,11}$/', $username)) {
   release('bufferflies', 'rainbows');
}
```

Comment: I would recommend always using `[0-9]`, not `\d` for the following reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex/891741#891741

Comment: @Matt: Depends on whether OP wants to accept ５５５６７８９ as a phone number :)

Comment: is there any speed advantages to `\d` over `[0-9]` I tend to use them interchangable with no ryme or reason.

Answer (score 3):

You need to anchor the regex to match the entire string:  `^[0-9]{10,11}$`.

`^` matches the beginning of a string; `$` matches the end.

Answer (score 1):

Limit usernames to only 10 characters and require there username to start with a letter.  How would a user write a 10 digit phone number as their username if they are required to enter in at least 1 alpha character (since phone numbers can't start with a 0/o or a 1/l)? (Heck I would require at least 3 alpha chars just to be safe).

When your app gets bigger then you can allow for longer usernames and take into account some of these issues:

Do not use ^ or $ signs if you are only testing the username: `if(do_reg($username, '/^\d{10,11}$/')){`

The reason I say this is anyone could defeat that by placing a letter in their username, a1235551212
instead use this:
`if(do_reg($username, '/\d{10,11}/')){` because that will flag a1235551212d

Also, importantly, remember, that all of these regular expressions are only checking for numbers, there's nothing to stop a user from doing the following: ltwo3for5six7890.  Unless of course you limit the username size.

Comment: I don't care if they use a number as a username persay. It's more of I don't want the possiiblity of a username matching a phone number. I am checking for unique phone numbers but when they login I want to be able to say `if ($login == $digits) {//use phone} else{ //use username} However, plus 1 for requiring at least one alpha character I like that idea :)

Comment: The plus one is in conjunction with the max length of 10 for the username.  I still recommend at least 3 alpha chars and the username starts with a char.  If you only use 1 alpha then the user could do 123555l2l2 (notice the L's).  What I was trying to get at in my last example is that ltwo3for5six7890 is actually a phone number in disguise.

Comment: yeah the problem isn't it being a phone number. Or even looking like a phone number. I'm storing my phone numbers at 11 digits in my database. So when they login I just need to make sure the username or the phonenumber match what they enterd on login. So if `ltwo3for5six7890` matched their username that's fine. I just don't want one user with `15555555555` as their username and another as `15555555555` as their phone number because then my query would return two results.

Answer (score 0):

You just should include start and end of the string in the regex

```
^[0-9]{10,11}$
```