# Regular expression for certain numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to generate a regular expression for the following situation.

1. a input box should accept numbers and dot in the following format XXX.XX.
2. It accepts also numbers as XX
3. It accepts also numbers as X
4. It accepts also numbers XX.XX
5. It accepts also numbers X.XX

I did like this: `/[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}$/`, but it satisfied only point number 1.

Comment: leading zeros allowed?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Comment: or `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: proves that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/8WZkf/1/

Comment: see jzelenkov 's jsfiddle, and tell how it not works?

Comment: @Andrew one important thing you should learn is to do negative tests. Testing all the positives is nice, but won't ensure, that the regex does exactly what it is intended to...

Comment: @Christoph, you mean leading zeros?

Comment: No, I mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8WZkf/6/

Comment: ya..its working...actually i tried with match() function..

Comment: @thg435: `\d` is not the same than `[0-9]`, it depends on locale, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/891741/372239

Comment: @M42: this is true for Perl and other unicode-aware regex engines. In javascript `\d` is defined as 0-9.