# \d+ regexp ignores minus at the beginning

Tags: regex, perl

I faced behaviour of Perl, that I can't explain:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $number = -10;
if ($number =~ /\d+/) {
    print $number;
}
```

This prints `-10`, despite the fact, that

- \d represents [0-9]

Why does it ignore minus at the beginning?

Comment: `\d` is not always the same as `[0-9]`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/890686/372239

Comment: @M42 So, \d can also match Hebrew, Armenian and other non-standard numbers, present in Unicode table?

Comment: @M42 which perl version started using `/a` modifier?

Comment: @mpapec: I think it was 5.14

Comment: `/\d+/` simply means "does the string contain a sequence of one or more digits?" Your string contains two digits and therefore matches. What alternative behaviour were you expecting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should match against the beginning of the string also with a ^:

```
if ($number =~ /^\d+/) {
```

Comment: yes, of course. To match the whole string, I should use ^\d+$

Answer (score 2):

Minus is a symbol, not number, so use:

```
if ($number =~ /^-?\d+$/) {
    print $number;
}
```

`-?` say that minus `-` symbol can meet one or zero times

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use a capture group and print `$1`, otherwise this would be my prefered answer :)

Comment: Do you mean `/^-?(\d+)$/`? And where do you want to use `$1`?

Comment: No like `/^(-?\d+)/` and using `$1` to see what was matched, but whatever.

Comment: Ok, I add capture group :) but in `if` statement I think it isn't necessary

Comment: There're no needs to use a capture group in this case. It slows down the script.

Comment: Hmmm, only if you want to use the result in `print $1`. Actually I'm not entirely sure what the goal of the match in the OP question is :-/ If he doesn't use it the group slows down the match considerably. I just thought he wants to act on the matched data and thus including the `-` and `\d` in a group would have been a good idea, but re-reading the question I'm not that sure anymore.

Comment: I also probably do not fully understand, but I think you're right. I not know well how to use matches in Perl, I write on PHP

Comment: Ah ok. If you leave the print statement as is you'de have to remove the braces again (sorry for confusing oyu in the first place ^^)

Answer (score 1):

You can write this as

```
if ($number and $number !~ /\D/) {
  print $number;
}
```

which checks that the string isn't zero-length and doesn't contain any non-digit characters.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is the purpose of \d+ or [0-9]+ , its doing correct thing only. It depends upon your  requirement what else you want like mixture of integers or just negative number to match or positive number to match or beginning, end, anywhere etc. All depends upon the pattern you want to develop.