# Perl assign regex match groups to variables

Tags: regex, perl, grouping

I'have a string in a following format: `_num1_num2`. I need to assign `num1` and `num2` values to some variables. My regex is `(\d+)` and it shows me the correct match groups on Rubular.com, but I don't know how to assign these match groups to some variables. Can anybody help me? Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That should be (assuming your string is stored in '`$string`'):

```
my ($var1, $var2) = $string =~ /_(\d+)_(\d+)/s;
```

The idea is to grab numbers until you get a non-number character: here '`_`'.

Each capturing group is then assign to their respective variable.

---

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890734/6309) (and [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967146/perl-assign-regex-match-groups-to-variables/23967193?noredirect=1#comment36934018_23967193) below by [Kaoru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259383/kaoru)):

> `\d` can indeed match more than 10 different characters, if applied to Unicode strings.

So you can use instead:

```
my ($var1, $var2) = $string =~ /_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)/s;
```

Comment: hey!, I don't know perl but if we *match* `\d+`, won't `num1` and `num2` matched?

Comment: @AmitJoki not if both numbers are separated by a non-number '_'.

Comment: Oh, thank you, it works. Could you also explain the regex please? I want to understand so I can do it myself next time. Particulary why it doesn't return `_` and what is `gs`?

Comment: @VonC, so it doesn't work the way javascript does. For example `"_12_24".match(/\d+/g)` returns `["12", "24"]`.

Comment: @AmitJoki Yes, each capturing group would only get one number here.

Comment: @AmitJoki you can see more at http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_06.html#Q2FwdHVyaW5n for instance.

Comment: Note that the \d shorthand can be a bit dangerous when running against unicode/character strings because it will match non-digit number characters.

Comment: @Kaoru Ok, I have edited the question accordingly, and added a link to another SO question which is about the issue you mention.

Answer (score 3):

Using the g-modifier also allows you to do away with the the grouping parenthesis:

```
my ($five, $sixty) = '_5_60' =~ /\d+/g;
```

This allows any separation of integers but it doesn't verify the input format.

Comment: Yes, this is what I would write. +1 for clarity and brevity

Answer (score 1):

The use of the global flag in the first answer is a bit confusing. The regex */_(\d+)_(\d+)/* already captures two integers. Additionally the g modifier tries to match multiple times. So this is redundant.

IMHO the g modifier should be used when the number of matches is unknown or when it simplifies the regex.

As far as I see this works exactly the same way as in JavaScript.

Here are some examples:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $str_a = '_1_22'; # three integers seperated by an underscore

# expect two integert

# using the g modifier for global matching
my ($int1_g, $int2_g) = $str_a =~ m/_(\d+)/g;
print "global:\n", Dumper( $str_a, $int1_g, $int2_g ), "\n";

# match two ints explicitly
my ( $int1_e, $int2_e) = $str_a =~ m/_(\d+)_(\d+)/;
print "explicit:\n", Dumper( $str_a, $int1_e, $int2_e ), "\n";

# matching an unknown number of integers
my $str_b = '_1_22_333_4444';
my @ints = $str_b =~ m/_(\d+)/g;
print "multiple integers:\n", Dumper( $str_b, \@ints ), "\n";

# alternatively you can use split
my ( $int1_s, $int2_s ) = split m/_/, $str_a;
print "split:\n", Dumper( $str_a, $int1_g, $int2_g ), "\n";
```