# Regex Expression for Bulgarian (valid) Date format d.M.yyyy 'г.'

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, localization, date-format

I need regex for Bulgarian date format- `d.M.yyyy 'г.'`
For date format- dd.MM.yyyy the below regex works:

```
/^\d\d?\.\d\d?\.\d\d\d?\d?$/
```

Need regex for Bulgarian date format- `d.M.yyyy 'г.'` No fruitful results found for my searches anywhere. plz help

Answer (score 1):

Just add the 'г. ' part.

```
/^\d\d?\.\d\d?\.\d\d\d?\d? ?'г\.'$/
```

Please note that that the regex actually doesn't validate dates. For example the '20.20.2020' is considered as valid date.

**Edit for full validation:**
You can use something like this:

```
/^((31[.]0?[13578]|1[02][.](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((29|30)[.](0?1|0?[3-9]|1[1-2])[.](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[.](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[.](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((29)[.](0?2)[.](((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000))) 'г\.'$/
```

But as I said in the comment it's unreadable.

Also it's better to use "[0-9]" instead of "\d" because the last mean "all digits" not only 0123456789 but also these:

```
 ZERO:  0٠۰߀०০੦૦୦௦౦೦൦๐໐０
 ONE:   1١۱߁१১੧૧୧௧౧೧൧๑໑１
 TWO:   2٢۲߂२২੨૨୨௨౨೨൨๒໒２
 THREE: 3٣۳߃३৩੩૩୩௩౩೩൩๓໓３
 FOUR:  4٤۴߄४৪੪૪୪௪౪೪൪๔໔４
 FIVE:  5٥۵߅५৫੫૫୫௫౫೫൫๕໕５
 SIX:   6٦۶߆६৬੬૬୬௬౬೬൬๖໖６
 SEVEN: 7٧۷߇७৭੭૭୭௭౭೭൭๗໗７
 EIGHT: 8٨۸߈८৮੮૮୮௮౮೮൮๘໘８
 NINE:  9٩۹߉९৯੯૯୯௯౯೯൯๙໙９��
```

Source: [Should I use \d or [0-9] to match digits in a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex)

Comment: thanks, is there any way to validate dates using regex??

Comment: Yes but it's not a good idea. Your logic should be clear to the people that read your code. You should pay attention to different days in different months, leap years etc. The regex will be very ugly and completely unreadable.