# How to normalize Unicode digits in Java

Tags: java, unicode, normalization, digit, unicode-normalization

Is there any Java API to normalize Unicode digits into ASCII digits?

There is a normalization API in [JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) and [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Normalizer2.html) which seems not to able to handle this kind of normalization (since it's probably not called normalization by [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/))

What I need is to convert all forms of Unicode digits ([listed in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/891741/141438)) into [0-9]. A possible messy solution is 10 replace-all for any digit from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This is possible using [ICU4J Transliteration API](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general).
The following transliterator removes any non-ASCII character from a String except a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and dash (minus).

```
Transliterator trans = Transliterator.getInstance("Any-Latin; NFD; [^a-zA-Z0-9-] Remove");
System.out.println(trans.transform("۱۲۳456"));
```

Will print:

```
123456
```

---

**Another messy solution**

```
static final Pattern DIGIT_0 = Pattern.compile("[٠۰߀०০੦૦୦௦౦೦൦๐໐０]");
static final Pattern DIGIT_1 = Pattern.compile("[١۱߁१১੧૧୧௧౧೧൧๑໑１]");
static final Pattern DIGIT_2 = Pattern.compile("[٢۲߂२২੨૨୨௨౨೨൨๒໒２]");
static final Pattern DIGIT_3 = Pattern.compile("[٣۳߃३৩੩૩୩௩౩೩൩๓໓３]");
static final Pattern DIGIT_4 = Pattern.compile("[٤۴߄४৪੪૪୪௪౪೪൪๔໔４]");
static final Pattern DIGIT_5 = Pattern.compile("[٥۵߅५৫੫૫୫௫౫೫൫๕໕５]");
static final Pattern DIGIT_6 = Pattern.compile("[٦۶߆६৬੬૬୬௬౬೬൬๖໖６]");
static final Pattern DIGIT_7 = Pattern.compile("[٧۷߇७৭੭૭୭௭౭೭൭๗໗７]");
static final Pattern DIGIT_8 = Pattern.compile("[٨۸߈८৮੮૮୮௮౮೮൮๘໘８]");
static final Pattern DIGIT_9 = Pattern.compile("[٩۹߉९৯੯૯୯௯౯೯൯๙໙９��]");

public static final Pattern[] DIGIT_PATTERN_LIST = { DIGIT_0, DIGIT_1, DIGIT_2, DIGIT_3, DIGIT_4, DIGIT_5, DIGIT_6, DIGIT_7, DIGIT_8,
        DIGIT_9 };

/**
 * Converts any Unicode digits into their ASCII equivalent. For example given 23۹٤۴ returns 23944
 * 
 * @param str
 * @return
 */
public static String normalizeUnicodeDigits(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIGIT_PATTERN_LIST.length; i++) {
        Pattern dp = DIGIT_PATTERN_LIST[i];
        str = dp.matcher(str).replaceAll(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `Character.forDigit(...)` and `Character.digit(...)` should work.

```
public static char normalizeDigit(char c) {
  int d = Character.digit(c, 10);
  return (d >= 0) ? Character.forDigit(d, 10): c;
}
```

Iterate over all characters.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called [transliteration](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html).