# RegEx syntax and efficiency

Tags: regex

I know a lot of syntax ( c#,c, vb and so on ) hence my head is pretty full.

So I tend to write regex like this 
**edit2** : change word RegRex
   <strike>[0-9]{1,}[aA-zZ]{1,}</strike>

```
[0-9]{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,}
```

No `+`, `?`, `\d`, ...

Is there performance issues with this syntax?

**edit** : This question is wider than `/d` vs `[0-9]` syntax

Comment: Don't know about performance but `[aa-zZ]` does not match what you might expect

Comment: `{1,}=+`, `{1}=empty`, so `[0-9]+[A-Za-z]`

Comment: [Use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex), Regex: `[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\d is less efficient than \[0-9\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9)

Comment: you're right Avinash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of performance `{1,}` and `+` are equivalent, but the first has more characters to be read... And `{1}` is not necessary. That won't make much difference though.

More generally, it is not a matter of preference. If you have to match a numeric ID made of numbers from 1 to a big number, without `+` (or `{1,}`, or `*` using `\d` twice), that will be difficult

```
\d+
```

or

```
[0-9]+
```

or

```
[0-9][0-9]*
```

if you prefer.

Besides, `[aA-zZ]` matches `a`, `Z` (twice actually) and anything between `A` and `z`, including `[`, `]`, `_` ... (see an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Comment: I dont understand, wich RegEx i  cant write ? big number : ([0-9]{1,})

Comment: `{1,}` is equivalent to `+`, so you are using a `+`... and `*` can also be written `{0,}`

Comment: 1 to big number [1-9][0-9]*