# Why does Apache Commons consider '१२३' numeric?

Tags: java, unicode, number-systems, apache-commons-lang3

According to Apache Commons Lang's documentation for [`StringUtils.isNumeric()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-), the String '१२३' is numeric.

Since I believed this might be a mistake in the documentation, I ran tests to verify the statement. I found that according to Apache Commons it *is* numeric.

Why is this String numeric? What do those characters represent?

Comment: Perhaps they represent digits in some language. Not all languages use the symbols 0 to 9 to represent digits.

Comment: these are 1, 2 and 3 in hindi

Comment: You can get the integer value by `Integer.parseInt("१२३")`.

Comment: `"ⅯⅭⅯⅬⅩⅩⅩⅤ".isnumeric()` is also True (in Python, but presumably in Java too), as is `"⅕".isnumeric()`

Comment: See also: *http://stackoverflow.com/q/40156585/974555*

Comment: step 1: realize that those characters are not in your alphabet. step 2: realize that it is probably a different language. step 3: let google translate figure it out: https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%A9

Comment: @gerrit: But what about `"π".isnumeric()` or `"e".isnumeric()`?

Comment: @dan04 Those are not numbers, those are letters that are popular to represent particular constants. Note the difference between `ⅯⅭ` and `MC`.

Comment: That's why [\d is less efficient than \[0-9\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/995714). [Should I use \d or \[0-9\] to match digits in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/890686/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Not in Java.  In Java, `\d` is a synonym for `[0-9]`.  It won't match the Devanagari digits.

Comment: @Blip It's not Hindi. It is Devanagari numeral.

Comment: If you're using Firefox, get the Identify Characters extension!

Comment: @Sujan, isn't Hindi customarily written in Devanāgarī?

Comment: @AntonSherwood Yes, and so are Marathi, Bhojpuri, Awadhi, Magahi, Maithili, Nepali, Pali, Konkani, Bodo, Sindhi and Sanskrit and many more. Devanagari is a script, like Latin, Hindi, Marathi are languages like English.

Comment: @AshishPatil So how can Sujan say it's not Hindi (rather than “it's not necessarily Hindi”)?

Comment: Welcome to Unicode :)

Comment: its basically `sanskrit`, `0` was invented in this language, if you do a simple google search on sanskrit numbers you will get this check this for reference (http://www.2indya.com/2011/06/22/sanskrit-counting-1-to-100/)

Comment: Why did you think the documentation was in error?

Comment: GNU Calculator (Linux graphic app) also recognize it as numeric (however the result is showed int Arabic Numerals): १२३+0=123; १२३+100=223;  १२३+0=123; १२३+123=246

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Because that "CharSequence contains only Unicode digits" (quoting your [linked documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-)).

All of the characters return true for [`Character.isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)):

> Some Unicode character ranges that contain digits:
>
> - '\u0030' through '\u0039', ISO-LATIN-1 digits ('0' through '9')
> - '\u0660' through '\u0669', Arabic-Indic digits
> - '\u06F0' through '\u06F9', Extended Arabic-Indic digits
> - '\u0966' through '\u096F', Devanagari digits
> - '\uFF10' through '\uFF19', Fullwidth digits
>
> Many other character ranges contain digits as well.

`१२३` are Devanagari digits:

- `१` is [DEVANAGARI DIGIT ONE, `\u0967`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0967/index.htm)
- `२` is [DEVANAGARI DIGIT TWO, `\u0968`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0968/index.htm)
- `३` is [DEVANAGARI DIGIT THREE, `\u0969`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0969/index.htm)

Comment: @Joker_vD well, you've not specified which overload, so yes, sure: [`Integer.parseInt("222", 2)`](http://ideone.com/xDtkYY).

Comment: @Joker_vD It's not even hard; there are many unsupported languages. Even if so, there's the Chinise `亿`, which represents 10^8 -> this to the power of 3 would cause an overflow. *[List of numeral systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit#Numerals_in_most_popular_systems)*

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` will probably fail if digits are not meant to be consecutive (like the japanese numbers 1, 2, 3, ...)

Comment: @CedricReichenbach: The key distinction there is that while 亿 is *numeric* (by the standards of having one of the non-None values of Numeric_Type, in this case Numeric_Type=Numeric), it's not any sort of *digit*. (Even if it were, you wouldn't take it to the power of 3; you would raise the *radix* to various powers, not the *digits*.) `parseInt` requires digits, and perhaps confusingly, the `isNumeric` method in this question tests for decimal digit characters (General_Category=Decimal_Number) instead of any broader category of numeric characters.

Comment: The complete set of Devangari digits is `०१२३४५६७८९`.

Comment: What did Joker_vD say?

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 (s)he asked if there was a way to get `Integer.parseInt()` to throw an exception for a 3-character numeric input string.

Answer (score 59):

The symbol **१२३** is the same as 123 for the Nepali language or any other language using the [Devanagari script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) such as Hindi, Gujarati, and so on, and is therefore is a number for Apache Commons.

Comment: That thing almost looks like "123" in Arabic numerals.

Comment: Arabs got their numerals from Indians.

Comment: @rahul Arabic numbers are 1-9, not ١-٩ as commonly thought.

Answer (score 26):

You can use [`Character#getType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType-char-) to check the character's general category:

```
System.out.println(Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER == Character.getType('१'));
```

This will print `true`, which is an "evidence" that '१' is a *digit number*.

Now let's examine the unicode value of the '१' character:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString('१'));
// 967
```

This number is on the range of [Devanagari digits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-) - which is: `\u0966` through `\u096F`.

Also try:

```
Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.of('१');
System.out.println(block.toString());
// DEVANAGARI
```

[Devanagari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) is:

> is an abugida (alphasyllabary) alphabet of India and Nepal

"१२३" is a "123" (Basic Latin unicode).

Reading:

- [More details on the '१' character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0967/index.htm)
- [`StringUtils#isNumeric` implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java#StringUtils.isNumeric%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: It's more significant that they're of type `DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER` than that they're in the `DEVANAGARI` block. There are non-digit letters in that block too.

Answer (score 23):

If you ever want to know what properties a particular "character" has (and there are quite a few), go directly to the source: **Unicode.org**. They have research tools that can show you most anything you would care to know.

- If you want to see all of the properties of a specific character, try the following:

  [http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=१](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=%E0%A5%A7)

  or:

  http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=%E0%A5%A7
- If you want to see all characters classified as "decimal digits" (i.e. with number values of 0 through 9), try the following:

  http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Numeric_Type=Decimal:]
  <sup>( 550 Code Points -- currently / as of Unicode 9.0 )</sup>
- If you want to see all characters classified as "non-decimal digit numbers" (i.e. fractions, circled, etc), try the following:

  http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Numeric_Type=Numeric:]
  <sup>( 836 Code Points -- currently / as of Unicode 9.0 )</sup>
- If you want to see all characters classified as "decimal digits" (i.e. with number values of 0 through 9), *but only up through Unicode 6.0 (which .NET uses)*, try the following:

  http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Numeric_Type=Decimal:]%26[:Age=6.0:]
  <sup>( 420 Code Points -- and shouldn't change )</sup>
- If you want to see all characters classified as "decimal digits" (i.e. with number values of 0 through 9), but only up through Unicode 6.0 (which .NET uses), *and only in the Base-Multilingual Plane / no Supplementary Characters (i.e. nothing above Code Point 65535 / U+0xFFFF)*, try the following:

  http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Numeric_Type=Decimal:]%26[:Age=6.0:]%26[:bmp=Yes:]
  <sup>( 350 Code Points -- and shouldn't change )</sup>

**KEEP IN MIND:** The Unicode Consortium produces a specification, not software. This means that it is up to each software vendor to implement the specification *as accurately as they can*. So just like HTML, JavaScript, CSS, SQL, etc, there is variation between different platforms, languages, and so on. For example, I found a bug in Microsoft's .NET Framework whereby circled Latin letters `A-Z` and  `a-z` -- Code Points 0x24B6 through 0x24E9 -- do not properly register as being `char.IsLetter = true` ([bug report here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2855376/char-isletter-incorrectly-reporting-false-for-circled-letters-and-supplementary-character-letters)). And that leads to unexpected behavior in related functionality, such as when calling the `TextInfo.ToTitleCase()` method ([bug report here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2855342/textinfo-totitlecase-incorrectly-treating-circled-letters-as-word-separators)).

Comment: Great references! (Though they do make me wonder if Unicode has gone over the top!)

Comment: If you want to have this sort of reference available locally, you could install [uniprops](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Unicode-Tussle-1.111/script/uniprops).

Comment: @TRiG Thanks for mentioning that. Interesting utility. It does cover some of the functionality shown in the first 3 links (the original set), but I just updated my answer to include some additional links that show more advanced queries that can be done on Unicode.org that I don't see possible via `uniprops`. Also, it appears that `uniprops` is one version behind as Unicode released version 9.0 this past June.

Answer (score 19):

Symbols '१२३' are actually derived from Hindi language(Basically from Sanskrit language i.e Devanagiri) which represent numeric values just like:

१ represent 1

२ represent 2

and like wise

Comment: CORRECTION: _Symbols '१२३' are actually derived from_ **Sanskrit** _language_ (i.e., Devanagiri script as other posters have noted)

Comment: I was surprised to learn how recently Devanāgarī took its present form – many centuries after Sanskrit was codified!  So I'm skeptical of the claim that the digits belong more to Sanskrit than to Indian culture in general.