# Integer.valueOf Arabic number works fine but Float.valueOf the same number gives NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception, arabic-support

Using Arabic number `Integer.valueOf("۱")` returns integer 1 but `Float.valueOf("۱")` or `Float.parseFloat("۱")` throws `NumberFormatException` while it won't throw any exceptions if you use English number `Float.valueOf("1")`, is it a bug in java or there's some explanation?

How can I parse such a number?

I'm working in android environment;

Comment: Did you read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Float.parseFloat("۱") gives NumberFormatException too. but Float.valueOf("1") returns float number 1.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that [`Float.parseFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)) does not support Eastern-Arabic numbers. Alternatively, you can use [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class:

```
Locale EASTERN_ARABIC_NUMBERS_LOCALE = new Locale.Builder()
                                                 .setLanguage("ar")
                                                 .setExtension('u', "nu-arab")
                                                 .build();
float f = NumberFormat.getInstance(EASTERN_ARABIC_NUMBERS_LOCALE)
                      .parse("۱٫۵")
                      .floatValue();
System.out.println(f);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1.5
```

Comment: in my case Locale.getDefault() gives the same as EASTERN_ARABIC_NUMBERS_LOCALE

Answer (score 5):

### Answer

In `Float.valueOf("۱")` there is no check for different languages or character, it only checks the digits `0-9`. `Integer.valueOf` uses [Character.digit()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/character-digit-in-java-with-examples/) to get the value of each digit in the string.

### Research/Explanation

I debugged the statement `Float.valueOf("۱")` with Intellij debugger. If you dive into FloatingDecimal.java, it appears this code determines which character should be counted as a digit:

```
  digitLoop:
        while (i < len) {
            c = in.charAt(i);
            if (c >= '1' && c <= '9') {
                digits[nDigits++] = c;
                nTrailZero = 0;
            } else if (c == '0') {
                digits[nDigits++] = c;
                nTrailZero++;
            } else if (c == '.') {
                if (decSeen) {
                    // already saw one ., this is the 2nd.
                    throw new NumberFormatException("multiple points");
                }
                decPt = i;
                if (signSeen) {
                    decPt -= 1;
                }
                decSeen = true;
            } else {
                break digitLoop;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

As you can see, there is no check for different languages, it only checks the digits `0-9`.

While stepping through `Integer.valueOf` execution,

`public static int parseInt(String s, int radix)`

executes with `s = "۱"` and `radix = 10`.

The parseInt method then calls `Character.digit('۱',10)` to get the digit value of `1`.

See [Character.digit()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/character-digit-in-java-with-examples/)

Answer (score 3):

The specification of [`Float.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) says:

> Leading and trailing whitespace characters in s are ignored.
>   Whitespace is removed as if by the String.trim() method; that is, both
>   ASCII space and control characters are removed. The rest of s should
>   constitute a FloatValue as described by the lexical syntax rules:
>
> ```
> FloatValue:
>   Signopt NaN
>   Signopt Infinity
>   Signopt FloatingPointLiteral
>   Signopt HexFloatingPointLiteral
>   SignedInteger
> ...
> ```

The closest lexical rule to what you have is [`SignedInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-SignedInteger), which consists of an optional sign, and then [`Digits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-Digits), which can only be `0-9`.

```
Digits:
  Digit
  Digit [DigitsAndUnderscores] Digit

Digit:
  0
  NonZeroDigit

NonZeroDigit:
  (one of)
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

On the other hand, [`Integer.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) refer to [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), which simply says:

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign

"Decimal digits" is broader than 0-9; anything in the [`DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-) can be used, for example ["१२३"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40148683/3788176) (shameless plug).

More precisely, .

---

So, this is behaving as specified; whether you consider this to be a correct specification is another matter.

Comment: @Ali np. Can I suggest you edit your question to ask for the solution, though ;)