# Regular expression to Allow 1st character as Alphabet and then numbers only

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression to allow first character be an alphabet and
then numbers only with following constraints :

> -no space
>
> -no special characters

like `AS2, Nf2, nf_2, nf 08` should not be allowed.
`'N00044,n0,n09,n099,123456,123'`  allowed

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]\d*$` , or `^[a-zA-Z]\d+$` if you want to ensure there is at least one number present.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Should there be both capitals and lowercase allowed? In your question it isn't clear what is and what isn't

Comment: yes(1st char only)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen already gave you the answer in his comment above. `*` means zero or more times, `+` means 1 or more times. Pick what you need.

Comment: cehck this one https://regex101.com/r/R8dHTY/3

Comment: @KaushikThanki your regex also matches an alphabet following the first alphabet and hence doesn't meet the criteria.

Comment: @DhavalSimaria i not sure , can give me some sample which fails my regex

Comment: `NF2` for instance, @KaushikThanki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jarvis's does meet the requirement but you can also use **numeric range** for the same since `\d` is specifically used for **ASCII numbers**.  [Refer when to use \d and [0-9].](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex)

Since numbers are required to be matched in your regex I would prefer as follows:

```
 ^([A-z][0-9]+)$
```

[Regex101- test cases](https://regex101.com/r/UQJTmH/1)

As per your requirement in comments, following regex should do the work for you:

```
^(([A-z][0-9]+)|([0-9]+))$
```

[Regex101- New test cases](https://regex101.com/r/UQJTmH/4)

It will match an input with **alphabet followed by numbers** or an input with **only numbers**.

Comment: could you tell me check above or all numeric characters i.e 'N00044' or '123456' is correct  (adding numeric char) either the above works or all numeric conditions

Comment: @AkhilJain Will you please elaborate. I didn't understand your question in comment properly.

Comment: "123456,123,n003,g123" should match

Comment: @AkhilJain Updated the answer as per your requirements in comments.

Comment: @AkhilJain Please check the answer and the test-case link now. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex :

```
^[A-z]\d+$
```

if you want a minimum of 1 digit necessary, or

```
^[A-z]\d*$
```

if having a digit is not mandatory.

Comment: Depending on the flavor of regex, your query might not match both lowercase and uppercase characters in the first position.

Comment: Yes, I purposely mentioned that regex since alphanumeric include both uppercase as well as lowercase letters. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Nice trick, didn't know that `[A-z]` covers both upper and lower case +1

Comment: For those who might be interested, `[a-Z]` won't work because `Z` comes before `a` in the character sequence.

Comment: @Jarvis above is correct could you tell me check above or all numeric characters 'N00044' or '123456' is correct

Comment: Can you elaborate ? I don't understand what you are asking. @AkhilJain

Comment: @Jarvis check above or all numeric characters i.e 'N00044' or '123456' is correct (adding numeric char) either the above works or all numeric condition