# Specific string format in java

Tags: java, string, format

I want to validate a String in java that contains the following order:

> SAVA950720HMCLZL04

That is, four letters, six numbers, six letters and finally two numbers.

I was reading about Regular Expressions but I can't understand how to implement it.

I did this method to validate the first four letters.

```
 public void name(String s){
 Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z]{4}");
 Matcher mat=pat.matcher(curp);
 if(mat.matches()){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Validating");
 }else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check your data. please", "error",JOptionPane.ERROR);
 }
 }
```

I think that I might be wrong because I don't know how to implement it correctly, any help about what might be the correct solution to my problem?.

Comment: Note that [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970). The `matches()` method anchors the regex, so you can only match strings of 4 chars. So, you need `matches("[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{2}")`

Comment: `A-z` should be `A-Z`. To represent digits use `[0-9]` or `\d` (in String literals you need to additionally escape ``\`` so it will look like `"\\d"`). Also `matches()` checks if regex can match entire string, not just part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Regex pattern in your case would be:

```
[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}
```

Find matching is simple:

```
public void name(String s){
    String pattern = "[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}";
    boolean match = s.matches(pattern);
    if (match) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can test regex from here https://regex101.com/

**Edit**

I used [0-9] instead of \d to ensure the safety matching for only digits. More details can be found here: [Should I use \d or [0-9] to match digits in a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 0):

1. `Matcher.match` attempts to match entire String against the pattern and your current pattern validates only 4 characters. Here is what you can do to test you regular expression:

   - You can put `.*` at the end of regular expression to match rest of the String
   - You can alternatively use `Matcher.find` or `Matcher.lookingAt` to match against substring
2. Your pattern has a typo, second interval is too wide `A-z` vs `A-Z`

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex pattern:

```
[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{6}[a-zA-Z]{6}\d{2}
```

The above will validate for four letters, six numbers, six letters and finally two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.stackoverflow._42635543;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{2}");

    if (pat.matcher("SAVA950720HMCLZL04").matches()) {
        System.out.println("match");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no match");
    }

    if (pat.matcher("SAVA950720HMCLZL045").matches()) {
        System.out.println("match");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no match");
    }
  }
}
```

produces

```
match
no match
```