# How can Separate a number from a text in Android?

Tags: android, separator

this is my code :

```
String addchar = "";
String tempchar;
int len = strline.length();
char[] chars = strline.toCharArray();
int amount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    tempchar = String.valueOf(chars[i]);
    if (tempchar == "0" || tempchar == "1" || tempchar == "2" || tempchar == "3" || tempchar == "4" || tempchar == "5" || tempchar == "6" || tempchar == "7" || tempchar == "8" || tempchar == "9") {
        addchar=tempchar+addchar;
    }
}

amount=Integer.parseInt(addchar);
```

but when run this code , I see that `amount` is empty!
I want to extract , the number that there is in `strline`

Comment: What sort of input are you expecting?

Comment: My number is signed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly less elegant than Nilesh's answer, but as an alternative:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : strline.toCharArray()) {
    if ((sb.length() == 0 && "-".equals(c)) || Character.isDigit(c)) sb.append(c);
}

int amount = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
```

**Edit** Amended to allow for initial negative sign

Comment: I have another problem : My number is signed How can I get number sign (-or+)?

Comment: Updated my answer. It'll allow for a minus sign so long as no digits have yet been found. Ignoring + as lack of a minus will infer a positive value.

Answer (score 1):

try this use Matcher

```
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("a22dsdddd212");
while(matcher.find()) {
    Log.e("number :-> ",matcher.group()+"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all numeric char, you can use replaceALL in this way:

```
String numericString = strline.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

then use ParseInt.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also an option, though using \\d may be better

Comment: `\d` may not work in comination with parseInt. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex for some differences between `\d`and `0-9`

Comment: @AzadGh If any of these answers have helped, please accept the answer by clicking the ✓

Comment: @AzadGh Click the check to the left of my answer to accept it

Comment: I have another problem
My number is signed
How can I get number sign ?