# regex to exclude [0-9] and string 'any'

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regex that should exclude all digits and a string 'any'. I tried with `/any|[0-9]/mig`. that is to include. as I am a novice to regex, I don't know the proper way to exclude.

Comment: any is a string just like 'anubhava' or 'chaitanya' or 'any'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all you wanted is to select anything but digits or the word any. You didn't mention to replace any sort of that stuffs. So, if I have to give you a pure regex solution then it is possible to meet your criteria, but that will need negative lookbehind as well!!! Which I think java script only supports in google chrome.

You may try this:

```
[^any\d]|a(?!ny)|(?<=a)n(?!y)|(?<!a)n(?=y)|n(?!y)|(?<!an)y
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQVBs6/5)

A javascript compatible solution for the above regex would be:

```
[^n]y|[^a]ny|a(?!ny)|an(?!y)|[^a]n(?=y)|n(?!y)|[^any\d]
```

[Javascript version Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQVBs6/9)

```js
const regex = /[^n]y|[^a]ny|a(?!ny)|an(?!y)|[^a]n(?=y)|n(?!y)|[^any\d]/g;
const str = `I successfully mande a regex to include it is any 0-9 but don't know the way to exclude. any zny znk anz ny any n a n y y ny ay zy any`;
let m;
var result="";
while((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        result+=m[0];
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, rizwan! Please let me know the documentation from where I can learn it.

Comment: Learn the regex expression that I have shared ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
function remove(input) {
 return input.replace(/any|[0-9]+/ig,'');
}

console.log(remove('testANy2948234 me'));
```

Notice that `/any|[0-9]+/ig` matches "any" in "many". Of that isn't what you want, replace it with `/\bany\b|[0-9]+/ig`. `\b` matches a word break.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/\d/` or `[0-9]`

Try this

```js
var text="123haiany g Baby";
console.log(text.replace(/any|[\d]/mig, ''));
```

Please take a look for if you want : [Should I use \d or [0-9] to match digits in a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex)

Comment: @guest271314 That's what i need test it before post the answer :( Sorry for it

Comment: I pretty sure you want `/any|\d+/ig`

Comment: @some , I want [0-9] and 'any' should not be included without using any javascript methods

Comment: @ChaitanyaChauhan: If you don't provide all the necessary information in question, you will get answers based on our interpretation only.

Comment: @ChaitanyaChauhan Did you say it in your question?

Comment: my bad, I didn't add that I want it without any javascript function. please check the improvised question.