# How can i create a new column in R that will return specific values according to the initial values in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this :

| names |
| --- |
| MARY123L |
| MARYL123.00 |
| MARYNLO |
| MARYNLA |
| JOHN330 |
| JOHNNLA |
| JOHN123A |
| JOHN123n456.00 |
| GEORGEJ |
| GEORGEJ |
| GEORGEJ |
| GEORGENLA |

i want to create a new column variable that  will check  each element in the column name and will return a word according to a condition :

1. if the word in the column names  ends with a letter to give me the word "table",
2. f the word in the column names  ends with a number to give me the word "chair"
3. and if the word in the column names  ends with a "NLA" or "NLO" to give me the word "clothing"

Ideally i want the new data frame to look like this:

| names | var |
| --- | --- |
| MARY123L | table |
| MARYL123.00 | chair |
| MARYNLO | clothing |
| MARYNLA | clothing |
| JOHN330 | chair |
| JOHNNLA | clothing |
| JOHN123A | table |
| JOHN123n456.00 | chair |
| GEORGEJ | table |
| GEORGEJ | table |
| GEORGEJ | table |
| GEORGENLA | clothing |

How I can do this in R using dplyr?

```
library(tidyverse)
names = c("MARY123L","MARYL123.00","MARYNLO","MARYNLA",
          "JOHN330","JOHNNLA","JOHN123A","JOHN123n456.00","GEORGEJ","GEORGEJ","GEORGEJ","GEORGENLA")
DATA = tibble(names);DATA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the `$` (ends with) [metacharacter](https://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end) is what you are looking for.

```r
DATA  |>
    mutate(
        var = case_when(
            grepl("NLA$|NLO$", names) ~ "clothing",
            grepl("[0-9]$", names) ~ "chair", 
            grepl("[[:alpha:]]$", names) ~ "table",
            TRUE ~ "Something has gone wrong - this should never appear"
        )
    )

# A tibble: 12 x 2
#    names          var     
#    <chr>          <chr>
#  1 MARY123L       table
#  2 MARYL123.00    chair
#  3 MARYNLO        clothing
#  4 MARYNLA        clothing
#  5 JOHN330        chair
#  6 JOHNNLA        clothing
#  7 JOHN123A       table
#  8 JOHN123n456.00 chair
#  9 GEORGEJ        table
# 10 GEORGEJ        table
# 11 GEORGEJ        table
# 12 GEORGENLA      clothing
```

#### Difference between `[[:alpha:]]$` and `[a-zA-Z]$`

I see another answer was posted at the same time which was pretty similar. It may get different results depending on your locale. For example:

```r
accented_sometimes  <- c(
    "This line ends with a letter", 
    "But this line ends with é"
)

grepl("[[:alpha:]]$", accented_sometimes)
# [1] TRUE TRUE
grepl("[a-zA-Z]$", accented_sometimes)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

There can also be differences between `\\d` and `[0-9]` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890686/should-i-use-d-or-0-9-to-match-digits-in-a-perl-regex) for more. I suspect this depends heavily on which R you are using - I am using 4.1 on Windows which does not have Unicode support but any later version or the same version on Linux/Mac will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA |> 
  mutate(var = case_when(str_detect(value, "NLA$|NLO$") ~ "clothing",
                         str_detect(value, "\\d+$") ~ "chair",
                         str_detect(value, "[a-zA-Z]$") ~ "table"))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   value          var     
   <chr>          <chr>   
 1 MARY123L       table   
 2 MARYL123.00    chair   
 3 MARYNLO        clothing
 4 MARYNLA        clothing
 5 JOHN330        chair   
 6 JOHNNLA        clothing
 7 JOHN123A       table   
 8 JOHN123n456.00 chair   
 9 GEORGEJ        table   
10 GEORGEJ        table   
11 GEORGEJ        table   
12 GEORGENLA      clothing
```