# sed substring operations based on pattern match

Tags: parsing, sed, substring

I have a series of datetimes with the format `%Y_%m_%dT%H%M%S`. I'm writing a series of sed commands in order to produce the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S`. I know that I can *extract* the time section easily; but upon extraction is there a way to split? I would think of  techniques such as lookahead capturing that might work in grep, e.g. `s/(\d{2})(?\d)/$1:/g`, but this doesn't seem to work.

(I know there's a way to perform substring operations in awk. But since sed is *the* stream editor I'd prefer to stretch my skills and learn how to do it via that tool instead.)

Example:
Input: `2023_01_01T123000`
Output: `2023-01-01 12:30:00`

Comment: There are numerous regex flavors. Sed typically supports BRE/ERE, which do not have features like lookarounds and do not support escapes like `\d`. Also, backreferences syntax is `\N`, so you'll need `\1` instead of `$1`. You can use `perl -pe 's/search/replace/g'` for advanced regex features.

Comment: @Sundeep You're absolutely right about that `$` -> `\\`, I was writing this on the fly in my phone - thanks for catching that. I'll try Perl, but is there a way to perform it in sed that I'm not thinking of that doesn't necessarily implement lookaround?

Comment: Can you add input/output examples?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Added an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can just capture and later reference each `%` part:

```
$ echo 2023_10_05T174803 \
| sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)_\([01][0-9]\)_\([0-3][0-9]\)T\([0-2][0-9]\)\([0-5][0-9]\)\([0-5][0-9]\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'
2023-10-05 17:48:03
```

You can use Perl to have a simpler regex, but it gives you no advantages in this case:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d{4})_([01]\d)_([0-3]\d)T([0-2]\d)([0-5]\d)([0-5]\d)/$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6/'
```

Also note that `\d` also matches other digits than just [0-9], see https://stackoverflow.com/a/891741/1030675 for details.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed or any sed that supports ERE:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'
```

If the datetimes are the only inputs we can simplify a bit:

```
sed -E 's/_/-/g;s/T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/ \1:\2:\3/'
```

Or even:

```
sed -E 's/_/-/g;s/T(..)(..)(..)/ \1:\2:\3/'
```